# reading numerical bytes from a text file

Tags: c++, c, file-processing

I have an input file that has 16 bit int addresses. For each entry in the list, I need to read in 8 bits for a "page number", and 8 bits for an "offset". Any idea how I could do this? I don't find any support for doing bitwise operations in c.

Comment: You can use `fread` to read binary data.

Comment: What language are you using? `C` or `C++`?

Comment: ***I don't find any support for doing bitwise operations in c*** There are shifts, and, or, xor ...

Answer (score 2):

Read your text file into an array of 16-bit elements, and then separate the high and the low portions like this:

```
uint16_t num;
uint8_t low = num & 0xFF;
uint8_t high = (num >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: how would you read in a byte from a string of digits though? I'm not exactly sure how to parse the string into numerical bytes. (I don't mean individual characters)

Comment: @JohnDodson Sorry, I somehow missed the "text file" part.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, instead of getting two int values I get a bunch of random characters

Comment: @JohnDodson "random characters"? Probably, you are not printing them right?